What AWG (cable thickness) do RJ45 jacks take for ethernet cable?
In the past I've used some thick Cat6 cable that wouldn't phyiscally fit in to an RJ45 connector. I'm about to buy a roll of Cat6 and I want to avoid the same problem, since the ones I'm looking at are made with different AWG's.
What is the thickest AWG that will fit in to an RJ45 jack?

In general network cable with solid copper wires (and/or additional foil shielding) is intended for keystone modules and not for RJ45 connectors. The more flexible stranded copper network cable usually intended for “patch” cables and RJ45 connectors. But you can crimp RJ45 connectors to both, but not every RJ45 connector will work well with both because the standards for RJ45 only define exterior, not interior dimensions. RJ45 connectors for shielded cables and those supporting solid copper and/or CAT7 are more like to accommodate thicker wires than standard run-of-the-mill RJ45 connectors.

IME there are special RJ45 connectors for CAT6(A) stranded which have the wire ports staggered rather than straight across. Electrically they are probably identical but the alternating high and low wire placement allows space for the slightly thicker insulation of CAT6.

24 AWG is fairly common. 23 probably has larger RJ45 applications.
